# Equivalent of `math.remainder` in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the equivalent of [`math.remainder()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/math.html#math.remainder) function in NumPy?  Basically I would like to compute `y = x - np.around(x)` for a NumPy array `x`.  (It is important that all elements of `y` have absolute at most 1/2).  Looking at NumPy documentation neither [`np.fmod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.fmod.html#numpy.fmod) nor [`np.remainder`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.remainder.html) do the job.

Obviously, I thought about writing `x - np.around(x)` but I am afraid that for large values of `x` subtraction produces floating-point inaccuracies.  For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1000) * 1e-9
x = a / 1e-9
y = x - np.around(x)
```

Should produce an all-zero vector `y`, but in practice there will be some errors (that get larger if I increase the size of arrays from 1000 to 10000).

The reason I am asking this question is to figure out if there is a NumPy function for this purpose that calls directly C math library `remainder` (as `math.remainder` must do) so as to minimize the floating-points errors.

Comment: .......  Use `%`?

Comment: `%` is equivalent to `np.remainder`

Comment: I don't understand your question: you ask for the numpy equivalent to `math.remainder`, but say `np.remainder` doesn't do the job. What does it do differently? And how does that relate to the `x - np.around(x)` computation you want to do?

Comment: @Energya the documentation says that the sign of `np.remainder` result depends on the sign of the divisor (and for `np.fmod` will be the sign of dividend).  This means both of them can produce results larger than 1/2 in absolute value.  Whereas `math.remainder` (equivalent of C math library `remainder`) gives output less than 1/2.

Comment: from the [man page of remainder](https://linux.die.net/man/3/remainder): `math.remainder(29.0, 3.0)` is `-1`

Comment: @SamMason What's your point?  It is still satisfies `abs(r) <= 0.5*abs(y)` (where `r` is the return value and `y` is the divisor).

Comment: @PBM sorry, wasn't concentrating, forgot how maths was supposed to work!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this currently exists `numpy`.  That said, the automagic [`numpy.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) call does the right thing for me, e.g:

```
import math
import numpy as np

ieee_remainder = np.vectorize(math.remainder)

ieee_remainder(np.arange(5), 5)
```

this broadcasts over the parameters nicely, giving:

```
array([ 0.,  1.,  2., -2., -1.])
```

which might be what you want.

performance is about 10 times slower than you'd get with a native implementation.  given an array of 10,000 elements my laptop takes approximately the following times:

- 1200 µs for `ieee_remainder`
- 150 µs for a Cython version I hacked together
- 120 µs for a C program doing a naive loop
- 80 µs for `numpy.fmod`

given the complexity of [glibc's `remainder` implementation](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_remainder.c) I'm amazed it's as fast as it is.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, vectorize is the correct solution.
However, if it's considered too slow, I suggest using this:

- First get the floor modulo
- then the centered modulo by subtracting around or rint

Like this:

```
def np_remainder(x,y)
    positive_modulo = x % y
    centered_modulo = positive_modulo - y * numpy.rint(positive_modulo / y)
    return centered_modulo
```

I think that numpy.fmod is exact, and using it avoid the problems of large rint values.
Since rint will be either 0 or 1 for y>0, the second operation will also be exact (either subtract 0 or y, which should be exact thanks to Sterbenz lemna).
Hence, the formulation above should not introduce any inaccuracy, unlike the raw formulation.

The difference with `numpy.vectorize(math.remainder)` will be on edge cases of exact tie:

- The workaround I'm proposing will always return a positive y/2 for y>0
- math.remainder will choose to round the quotient to nearest even and alternate -y/2 and y/2

Comment: `positive_modulo` is positive only when y>0. It is negative when y<0. Hence should better be renamed `floored_modulo`. Also `np_remainder` might be a confusing name, adding even more confusion to the already unfortunate naming used in numpy... I was short of a better name, as this was not my main point.